# Accessing a Sub-level in a Plist - How to?

Tags: objective-c, plist

ive been reading this site for a couple of months... still new to Obj-C and IOS...

So here goes my first question:

Im making a basic multiple choice quiz app and I want to be able to access the questions randomly from a plist file. So what im thinking is: have the question and answers grouped together in an array within a sub level of a plist (each sub level its own collection of questions and possible answers) each row in the plist can be pulled randomly upon pressing a UIButton and the corresponding question and answers will come with it. My code can them do its thing based on the pulled data...

https://skitch.com/carltaylor43/fj19q/quizquestions.plist-synthquizv2

So far I have no problem accessing anything from the root ("test1" or "test2" in this example) and can populate my Array with no problem...

I have been using this code to set the UITextField and it works fine:

```
question.text = [plistArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

so how would I access a sub level? I cant seem to find any info on the net or dev reference... please help :)

Comment: With sub level you mean the possible answers?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [plistArray objectAtIndex: 2]];
for (NSString *string in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
}
```

But in my opinion you should use a dictionary in your plist.

Comment: ah right.. so doing it this way would I have to make an array for every question? ..... BTW I have looked at the Dictionary stuff... I was under the impression that I can not have pictures and audio files in Dictionaries??? Thanks for the reply! :)

Comment: I put your code into my programme.. it prints out all the strings at the index.. cool! .. now I just need to figure out how to get them into my UITextLabels

Comment: ok.... ive tried for about 5 hours over 2 days and still can not get that plist to populate my question.text box... does anyone know the correct syntax to access???? question.text = [plistArray objectAtIndex:1];

Comment: BTW I thought it might be something like this? answerOne.text = [plistDict objectInSection:3 row:2];

Comment: Learn to read the documentation Apple provides. Saves you and us a lot of time!